# Android MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ignores if rules

Tags: android

Ran into some weird problem I cannot wrap my head around.

I have and MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE case:

```
if(event.getHistorySize() > 0){
       if(event.getHistoricalY(0, event.getHistorySize()/2) > event.getY()){
           Log.d("TRANSITION", "Finger Moving UP");
           changeToolbarToUpperColor();
       }else if(event.getHistoricalY(0, event.getHistorySize()/2) < event.getY()){
           Log.d("TRANSITION", "Finger Moving DOWN");
           changeToolbarToDownerColor();
       }

}
```

Here is the changeToolbarToUpperColor();

```
private void changeToolbarToUpperColor() {
    if(!ignoreUp){
        Log.d("TRANSITION", "Changing color to UPPER color");
        ignoreUp = true;
    }
}
```

Now after the first call the ignor goes true and the method should not pass if() anymore.

Why am I getting logs that are still printing "Changing color to UPPER color" all the time I move the finger in screen?

Thanks

Comment: where is ignoreUp defined? It could be that it goes out of scope each time if it's defined in the listener.

Comment: It is a global private variable defined before onCreateView()

Comment: So it's not final and it's not changed by any other method?

Comment: Correct. Its not final and the changeToolbarToUpperColor() is the only method to change its value to true. It is declared false in the beginning.

Comment: Is ACTION_MOVE perhaps running on different thread every time and not seeing the global variable?
 I have looked thorugh the whole code and find usage also shows ignoreUp being altered only in changeToolbarUpperColor() method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all of the motion events have to run on the same UI thread.